# Ignore namespace in XSLT

Tags: xslt

I have input file comes with different namespace.  However, for my requirement I need to handle it with 1 xslt.

**Input file 1:**

```
    <header xmlns="urn:xyz:hello">
       <body>
           <element1>hi</element1>
           <element2>sen</element2>
       </body>
    </header>
```

**Input file 2:**

```
<header xmlns="urn:abc:hello1">
   <body>
       <element1>hi</element1>
       <element2>sam</element2>
   </body>
</header>
```

Similar to the above sample, I would get files with different namespace `urn:cdf:well, urn:cdf:hello, ....`

How do I handle this in 1 xslt?

Your advise is much appreciated.

Thanks
Sen

Comment: What do you actually mean by saying you "need to handle it". Do you simply want to remove the namespace, or do you actually want to transform the XML but retain the namespace, whatever namespace is used? It would help if you showed your expected output in each case. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the *identity template* use the following templates,
"deleting" any namespace.

```
<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*">
  <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Hi,I tried adding the above templates in my xslt. But output is null!

Comment: Probably your script has other, more specific templates and they are "executed" (instead of mine). Start with just these (mine) templates and add "old" templates one by one. Maybe these (old) templates should adopt my solution concerning omission of namespaces. Do your templates contain *apply-templates*?